Display Foreign Key Field in Responsive Column Template
I have a kendo grid with fields as below:
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyApp.Models.FlightLog>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.FlightLogID).Visible(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.FlightDate).Format("{0:d}").Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.AircraftID, @Model.Aircraft, "AircraftID", "Registration").Title("Aircraft").EditorTemplateName("ComboBox").Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.PersonID, @Model.Person, "PersonID", "FullName").Title("Pilot").EditorTemplateName("ComboBox").Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.OrganisationID, @Model.Organisation, "OrganisationID", "Name").Title("Client").EditorTemplateName("ComboBox").Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.Bound(p => p.FlightTime).Format("{0:n1}").Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Starts).Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Landings).Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Route).Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.Bound(p => p.TaskNumber).Media("(min-width: 450px)");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Locked).Media("(min-width: 450px)").Visible(false);
    columns.Template("#=resColTemplate(data)#").Title("Trip Record").Media("(max-width: 450px)");    

And a responsive column template:
<script id="responsive-column-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <p class="col-template-val"><strong>Date: </strong>#=kendo.toString(FlightDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")#</p>
    <p class="col-template-val"><strong>Registration: </strong>#=data.AircraftID#</p>
</script>

Main part of Model:
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

   public IEnumerable<Models.Aircraft> Aircraft { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<Models.Person> Person { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<Models.Organisation> Organisation { get; set; }

   public async Task OnGet()
   {
       Aircraft = await _context.Aircraft.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
       Person = await _context.Person.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
       Organisation = await _context.Organisation.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
   }
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
   {
       var flightLogs = await _context.FlightLog.AsNoTracking().ToList().ToDataSourceResultAsync(request);

       return new JsonResult(flightLogs);
   }
....

Instead of the AircraftID field, I would like to display Registration from the ForeignKey field.
Is that possible?

You can access the ForeignKey column data through the "values" property of the Grid columns. For example:
<script id="responsive-column-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # var foreignKeyColData = $("\\#grid").getKendoGrid().columns[2].values; # // Replace "2" with the index of the ForeignKey column
    # var getvalue = $.grep(foreignKeyColData, function(indx, item){ return (indx.value == data.AircraftID) });#
    <p class="col-template-val"><strong>Date: </strong>#=kendo.toString(FlightDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")#</p>
    <p class="col-template-val"><strong>Registration: </strong>#=getvalue[0].text#</p>
</script>


Access the Registration field directly from the data object in your template like this:
<script id="responsive-column-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
 <p class="col-template-val"><strong>Date: </strong>#=kendo.toString(FlightDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")#</p>
 <p class="col-template-val"><strong>Registration: </strong>#=data.Aircraft.Registration#</p>
</script>

Using data.Aircraft.Registration, you're accessing the Registration property of the Aircraft object associated with the AircraftID in your FlightLog model.

That gives me an undefined error.  Note that that the foreign key column uses a different model to that of the grid.  I have extended the code above in my op to help make it clearer.

Apologies, I didn't see your edit.  I am getting the following error now:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Registration').  I have added my model code, perhaps that is more important that I thought.

I have found the answer elsewhere, thanks for your help though.
